# How can I make my quickselect algorithm faster

Tags: algorithm, scala

I have taken a course that examines algorithms and we have an assignment to do the classic k:th smallest element (0 being the smallest and `sequence.length-1` being the biggest) with quickselect.

The algorithm should be on average 2*faster than the sorting method

```
Arrays.sort
```

My algorithm works but it isn't fast enough. It is on average 5 times slower than the above method for sorting arrays. Here is my implementation so far:

```
  def find(sequence: Seq[Int], k: Int): Int = {
    require(0 <= k && k < sequence.length)
    val a: Array[Int] = sequence.toArray[Int]
    select(a,k)
  }

  def select(a: Array[Int], k: Int): Int = {
    val pivot = rand.nextInt(a.length)     
    val (low, middle, high) = partition(a,a(pivot))
    if (low.length == k) a(pivot)
    else if(low.length > k) select(low, k) 
    else if (low.length + middle.length >= k+1) middle(0)
    else if (low.length == 0) select(high, k - low.length-middle.length)
    else  findFast(high, k - low.length-middle.length)
  }

  def partition(array: Array[Int],pivot: Int): (Array[Int],Array[Int],Array[Int])={
    (array.filter(_<pivot),array.filter(_==pivot),array.filter(_>pivot))
  }
```

Could you give me some tips with which to improve the runtime of my implementation?

Comment: Are you sure that `array.filter` works as fast as usual Hoare partition scheme? Seems it makes triple work!

Comment: also I see that scala has in-built `partition` https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-split-sequences-subsets-groupby-partition-scala-cookbook

Comment: Why do you use a random pivot position? If the array is already sorted, the middle element is the ideal choice because it cuts the work in half for each sub-section.

Comment: @MBo You're right! The array is iterated three times and that causes problems! The partition function is also problematic since I have to go through the array twice since I am dividing the array into three parts. Is there a way I could partition the array with one round of iteration?

Comment: make your test sequence 1000 times longer

Answer (score 2):

Though there are many posts on quickSelect in general and the standard template of pseudocode is good enough, I always struggle to find good implementation in Scala and the code from Rosetta blog is good but can potentially go into an infinite loop especially when one of the left or right partition array is sorted.

Below is a slightly modified and working solution with Scala (covers cases such as duplicate elements and sorted array).

Basically returning the kth element if the input array is sorted

```
def isSorted[T](arr: List[T])(implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Boolean = arr match {
        case Nil => true
        case x :: Nil => true
        case x :: xs => ord.lteq(x, xs.head) && isSorted(xs)
}
def quickSelect(nums: List[Int], k: Int): Int = {
        // if the input array is sorted then no point partitioning further
        // and go into a potential infinite loop even with random pivot
        // logical to pick the kth element from sorted array
        if (isSorted(nums)) return nums(k)
        // else start the partition logic
        val pvt = (new scala.util.Random).nextInt(nums.length)
        val (lower, higher) = nums.partition( _ < nums(pvt))
        if (lower.length > k) quickSelect(lower, k)
        else if (lower.length < k) quickSelect(higher, k - lower.length)
        else nums(pvt)
}
```

Hopefully, this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In your implementation `partition` function executes `array.filter` three times.

To avoid this, you can use Scala `partition` method as [Rosettacode shows](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Quickselect_algorithm#Scala) - note that code does not execute `partition` twice  (don't know about real run time)

```
import scala.util.Random


object QuickSelect {
  def quickSelect[A <% Ordered[A]](seq: Seq[A], n: Int, rand: Random = new Random): A = {
    val pivot = rand.nextInt(seq.length);
    val (left, right) = seq.partition(_ < seq(pivot))
    if (left.length == n) {
      seq(pivot)
    } else if (left.length < n) {
      quickSelect(right, n - left.length, rand)
    } else {
      quickSelect(left, n, rand)
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val v = Array(9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
    println((0 until v.length).map(quickSelect(v, _)).mkString(", "))
  }
}
```

or implement classic [Hoare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme) or Lomuto partition in Scala.

```
algorithm partition(A, lo, hi) is
    pivot := A[lo]
    i := lo - 1
    j := hi + 1
    loop forever
        do
            i := i + 1
        while A[i] < pivot
        do
            j := j - 1
        while A[j] > pivot
        if i >= j then
            return j
        swap A[i] with A[j]
```

Note that here work occurs in the same array/sequence (in-place approach) - is it suitable for Scala (mutability etc)? If not applicable - just traverse sequence, writing small items into `low` sequence, and larger items into `high` sequence. Pseudocode:

```
def partition(A,low,equal,high, pivot):
   for item in A:
      if item < pivot:
          low[lowidx++] = item
      elif item > pivot:
          high[highidx++] = item
      else:
          equal[eqidx++] = item
```

(while `equal` part is not really needed - you can get it's length from another lengths)